# Replace placeholders in PowerShell dictionary using dynamic method

Tags: xml, powershell, dictionary, powershell-2.0

Referring to [Replace placeholders with actual values in PowerShell dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42661150/replace-placeholders-with-actual-values-in-powershell-dictionary) 
Im trying to replace placeholders in PowerShell dictionary with actual element values `dynamically`. I have received an appropriate answer from the above post, But that doesn't help much since it was a static solution. The requirement changes frequently, So I cannot hardcode things in PowerShell script. I have made few changes to the PowerShell script and tried to run. But encountered some errors. Following is my code:

```
$xmldata = @"
<configuration>
    <environment id="Development">
    <type>Dev</type>
    <client>Arizona%%type%%</client>
    <dataSource>Local%%client%%</dataSource>
    <path>App_Data\%%type%%\%%client%%_%%dataSource%%</path>
    <targetmachines>
        <targetmachine>
        <name>Any</name>
        <remotedirectory>D:\Inetpub\Test</remotedirectory>
        </targetmachine>
    </targetmachines>
    </environment>
</configuration>
"@

[System.Xml.XmlDocument] $configxml = [xml]$xmldata
$environmentId = "Development"
$keyValuePairs = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.String]"
$configxml.SelectNodes("//configuration/environment[@id='$($environmentId)']//*[not(*)]") | `
    ForEach-Object {
                    if($_.ParentNode.ToString() -ne "targetmachine")
                    {

                        $keyValuePairs.Add($_.Name, $_.InnerText)
                    }
                }

Write-Output $keyValuePairs

Foreach ($key in $keyValuePairs.Keys)
{

    $strings = [regex]::Matches($keyValuePairs[$key], '%%([^/)]+?)%%') |ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value }
    $strings = $strings | sort -unique

    if ($strings.Count -gt 0)
    {
        $finalValue = $keyValuePairs[$key]
        $finalValue

        foreach ($placeholder in $strings)
        {
            write-host "one of the place holder is" -ForegroundColor Green
            $placeholder
            #replacing all of the placeholders (which exists between %%---%%) with actual values
            $finalValue = $finalValue.Replace("%%$placeholder%%",$keyValuePairs[$placeholder])
        }

        #Replace the original value with actual value
        $keyValuePairs[$key] = $finalValue 
    }
}

Write-Output $keyValuePairs
```

Getting following error while trying to override the dictionary value

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
At line:33 char:10
+ Foreach ($key in $keyValuePairs.Keys)
+          ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], InvalidOperationExcept 
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException
```

Note: Basically Im trying to replace the placeholders from all over the dictionary values using dynamic method. Can someone please help me how can achive the following output

```
Key                        Value
---                        -----
type                       Dev
client                     ArizonaDev
dataSource                 LocalArizonaDev
path                       App_Data\Dev\ArizonaDev_LocalArizonaDev
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script should work as expected **for given `xml` data set**. For more complicated *nested* placeholder structure, see `### loop while ...` comments (and think about it).

```
$xmldata = @"
<configuration>
    <environment id="Development">
    <type>Dev</type>
    <client>Arizona%%type%%</client>
    <dataSource>Local%%client%%</dataSource>
    <path>App_Data\%%type%%\%%client%%_%%dataSource%%</path>
    <targetmachines>
        <targetmachine>
        <name>Any</name>
        <remotedirectory>D:\Inetpub\Test</remotedirectory>
        </targetmachine>
    </targetmachines>
    </environment>
</configuration>
"@

[System.Xml.XmlDocument] $configxml = [xml]$xmldata
$environmentId = "Development"
$keyValuePairs = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.String]"
$configxml.SelectNodes("//configuration/environment[@id='$($environmentId)']//*[not(*)]") | `
    ForEach-Object {
                    if($_.ParentNode.ToString() -ne "targetmachine")
                    {

                        $keyValuePairs.Add($_.Name, $_.InnerText)
                    }
                }

"BEFORE---->"
Write-Output $keyValuePairs  | ft -AutoSize -Wrap

### loop while [Regex]::Matches($keyValuePairs.path,"%%(.+?)%%*") START

$aux = $($keyValuePairs.GetEnumerator())
for ($i=0; $i -lt $aux.Count; $i++) { 
    $auxKey = $aux[$i].Key
    $auxVal = $aux[$i].Value

    $m = [Regex]::Matches($keyValuePairs.path,"%%(.+?)%%*")
    $m | % {
        $tag = $_.Groups[1].Value
        if ( $tag -match '%%') {
            # wait until replaced
        } else {
            $keyValuePairs.$auxKey = $keyValuePairs.$auxKey -replace "%%$tag%%", $($keyValuePairs.$tag)
            $aux = $($keyValuePairs.GetEnumerator()) # renew values after replace
        }
    }
}
### loop while [Regex]::Matches($keyValuePairs.path,"%%(.+?)%%*") END

"AFTER---->"
Write-Output $keyValuePairs  | ft -AutoSize -Wrap
```

**Output**:

```
PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\SO\42687374.ps1
BEFORE---->

Key        Value                                      
---        -----                                      
type       Dev                                        
client     Arizona%%type%%                            
dataSource Local%%client%%                            
path       App_Data\%%type%%\%%client%%_%%dataSource%%


AFTER---->

Key        Value                                  
---        -----                                  
type       Dev                                    
client     ArizonaDev                             
dataSource LocalArizonaDev                        
path       App_Data\Dev\ArizonaDev_LocalArizonaDev
```

Comment: Thank you so much Josefz. It is working great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$xmldata = @"
<configuration>
    <environment id="Development">
    <type>Dev</type>
    <client>Arizona%%type%%</client>
    <dataSource>Local%%client%%</dataSource>
    <path>App_Data\%%type%%\%%client%%_%%dataSource%%</path>
    <targetmachines>
        <targetmachine>
        <name>Any</name>
        <remotedirectory>D:\Inetpub\Test</remotedirectory>
        </targetmachine>
    </targetmachines>
    </environment>
</configuration>
"@

$configxml = [xml] $xmldata
$dictionary = @{}

$environmentId = "Development"
$environment = $configxml.SelectNodes("//configuration/environment[@id='$($environmentId)']") | ?{ $_.Name -ne "targetmachines" }
$environment.ChildNodes  | %{
    $dictionary.Add($_.Name, $_.'#text')
}

$environment.ChildNodes | %{
    while ($_.'#text' -match '%%([^/)]+?)%%') {
        $key = $matches[1]
        $_.'#text' = $_.'#text'.Replace('%%' + $key + '%%', $dictionary[$key])
    }
}

$configXml.Save([Console]::Out)
```

Comment: Thank you David Brabant. it seems using this approach I can only update my xml file.