# Measure-object -average for values stored in percentage (%)

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I'm familiar with using the "measure-object" function to count, and get averages, etc, however, i'm having some difficult using it to get the average based on data that's stored in csv as percentage (%)

```
Platform    Cap Used %
P1          0%
P2          18%
```

I originally included logic in the script that generates the csv to save in % using the normal method "{0:P0}"

However, when i now try to run a measure-object -average on the "Cap Used %" array, i get the following error over and over again::

```
Measure : Input object "" is not numeric.
At line:1 char:36
+ $TempData | Select $_"Cap used %" |Measure -average
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:PSCustomObject) [Measure-       
 Object],PSInvalidOperationException
            + FullyQualifiedErrorId  :NonNumericInputObject,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MeasureObjectCommand
```

I'm able to sort the same data via the following code, but i'm not able to run it through measure-object -average

```
$TempData | Select {[int]($_."Cap Used %" -replace '%')}
```

I could probably store the data without the %, but i'd rather keep it intact. Is there an ez way to sum a bunch of percentages and get the average %? When i import the data into excel and select the column, the expected average result is shown, so i know the data is good, however, i believe excel has some extra logic built into it to auto-detected the correct data format

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [In general, when posting an example with `xml` or `csv` data, it is
>   helpful to use *here-strings* to represent the data instead of
>   referencing a file that others do not have.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42661644/3439404)

Next code snippet returns `8` as expected.

```
$hereStr=@'
Platform,"Cap Used %"
P1,0%
P2,18%
P3,6%
'@

$TempData = $hereStr | ConvertFrom-Csv
(($TempData."Cap Used %").Replace('%','') | Measure-Object -Average).Average
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try that code out shortly and report back